# How to get lambda expression parameters

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

In my particular scenario I dynamically build a SQL statement to search for records. This takes place server-side in WebApi at the business service layer. Now I want to extend this functionality so that the `WHERE` clause can be set on the client-side too. I would like to use strongly-typed so that I don't hard-code column names on the client.

So far I did the following:

1) Get the view's columns from the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` and fill a `Dictionary<string, object>` so that the column values are set at a later stage. I might change to a custom class so that I can add a comparer field instead of having just `column_name = column_value`.

2) I created a custom attribute and a class that includes only the search columns that I want to expose to the client:

```
public class CustomerSearchDto
{
    [SearchColumn(Name = "customer_type")]
    public CustomerType CustomerType { get; set; }

    [SearchColumn(Name = "city")]
    public string City { get; set; }

    public CustomerSearchDto()
    {  }
}
```

3) So in the client, now I can do:

```
//Following line is pseudo-code
var predicate = (x => x.CustomerType == CustomerType.Private);
```

How can I take this lambda expression, and having the column list from (1) and knowing the column names from (2), set the value of the corresponding column in the dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are too many assumptions, but you can start with something like this:

```
static void SetValue<T>(Dictionary<string, object> target, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
    var comparison = predicate.Body as BinaryExpression;
    Debug.Assert(comparison != null);
    var member = (comparison.Left.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert ?
        ((UnaryExpression)comparison.Left).Operand :
        comparison.Left) as MemberExpression;
    Debug.Assert(member != null);
    var value = comparison.Right as ConstantExpression;
    Debug.Assert(value != null);
    var attribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(member.Member, typeof(SearchColumnAttribute)) as SearchColumnAttribute;
    var columnName = attribute?.Name ?? member.Member.Name;
    var columnValue = value.Value;
    target[columnName] = columnValue;
}
```

Test:

```
Expression<Func<CustomerSearchDto, bool>> predicate = (x => x.CustomerType == CustomerType.Private);
var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
SetValue(dict, predicate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of building a dictionary and then a query from that, you could go from your client-side Expression to your SQL Expression in one step by rewriting it using an `ExpressionVisitor`.

Your `ExpressionVisitor` would override the appropriate method, e.g. `protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)` and inside that method it would convert the client-side field name to the server-side field name.

You still have the issue of serializing your Expressions client-side and deserializing them server-side but once you have them you can use the visitor to rewrite them for SQL.